# Swift combine repeat if (with delay) custom publisher

Tags: swift, recursion, reactive-programming, combine

I need to implement repeat if with delay custom publisher for Swift Combine. The purpose of it is to repeatedly poll backend endpoint with delay set from previous response.  It could be long polling (max 5min. with 3 - 6sec time period).  I tried to use recursive approach, but it is not working consistelty. It makes from 20 to 200 repeats randomly, and then there is fired finished on the former/first subsciption and rest of the subscrptions are finished also. Count of repeats probably depends on memory situation etc.. Any coments or hints how to implement described functionality in reactive way are welcome.

Playground: git@github.com:BenBella/repeatif-publisher-playground.git

```
enum CustomPublishers { }

extension CustomPublishers {
    struct RepeatIf<Upstream: Publisher>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Upstream.Output
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure

        init(
            upstream: Upstream, shouldRepeat: @escaping (Upstream.Output) -> Bool,
            withDelay: @escaping (Upstream.Output) -> Int
        ) {
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.shouldRepeat = shouldRepeat
            self.withDelay = withDelay
        }

        var upstream: Upstream
        var shouldRepeat: (Upstream.Output) -> Bool
        var withDelay: (Upstream.Output) -> Int

        func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Failure == Downstream.Failure, Output == Downstream.Input {
            upstream
                .print("CustomPublishers.RepeatIf(1)>")
                .flatMap { output in
                    Just((output)).setFailureType(to: Downstream.Failure.self)
                        .delay(for: .seconds(withDelay(output)),
                               scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
                }
                .flatMap { output in
                    shouldRepeat(output)
                    ? Self(upstream: upstream, shouldRepeat: shouldRepeat, withDelay: self.withDelay)
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    : Just((output)).setFailureType(to: Downstream.Failure.self)
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                .catch { (error: Upstream.Failure) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> in
                    return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                .print("CustomPublishers.RepeatIf(2)>")
                .receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to implement desired functionality with different approach, but I am still interested in any comments regarding to why recursive flatMap doesn't work. Thank you

Working solution:

```
func retryRequestWithDelay(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Response>, AppError> {
        let pollPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, AppError>(0)
        return pollPublisher.compactMap { [weak self] delay in
            return self?.networkingService.request(url)
                .delay(for: .seconds(delay), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
        }
        .switchToLatest()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [weak self] (response: Response) in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if response.status == .pending {
                self.pollPublisher.send(response.pollPeriod)
            } else {
                self.pollPublisher.send(completion: .finished)
            }
        })
        .filter { (response: Response) in
            guard response.data.status == .pending else { return true }
            return false
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: May be start looking at Timer.publish

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via two `flatMap()` calls:

```swift
extension CustomPublishers {
    struct RepeatIf<Upstream: Publisher>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Upstream.Output
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure

        init(upstream: Upstream,
             shouldRepeat: @escaping (Upstream.Output) -> Bool,
             withDelay delay: @escaping (Upstream.Output) -> Int) {
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.shouldRepeat = shouldRepeat
            self.delay = delay
        }

        private var upstream: Upstream
        private var shouldRepeat: (Upstream.Output) -> Bool
        private var delay: (Upstream.Output) -> Int

        func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Failure == Downstream.Failure, Output == Downstream.Input {
            upstream
                .flatMap { (output: Output) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> in
                    guard shouldRepeat(output) else {
                        return Just(output)
                            .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }

                    return Just(())
                        .delay(for: .seconds(delay(output)), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                        .flatMap { () -> RepeatIf<Upstream> in
                            return RepeatIf(upstream: upstream, shouldRepeat: shouldRepeat, withDelay: delay)
                        }
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}

extension Publisher {
    func repeatIf(shouldRepeat: @escaping (Output) -> Bool,
                  withDelay delay: @escaping (Output) -> Int) -> CustomPublishers.RepeatIf<Self> {
        .init(upstream: self, shouldRepeat: shouldRepeat, withDelay: delay)
    }
}
```

The outer `flatMap` will either return the value, if no retry should be made, or it flatMap's over a dummy published whose scope is just to provide a starting point for the `delay` operator.

Example usage:

```swift
// this is a simple publisher that provides an incremented value each time
// a subscription occurs
var cnt = 0
let future = Deferred {
    Future<Int, Never> { promise in
        cnt += 1
        promise(.success(cnt))
    }
}

// let's test this baby
let subscription = future
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { print("\(Date()): original value: \($0)") })
    .repeatIf(shouldRepeat: { $0 < 5 }, withDelay: { $0 })
    .sink(receiveValue: { print("\(Date()): final value: \($0)") })

// making sure we wait for all events to be received
// and makins sure the subscription doesn't deallocate while we wait
withExtendedLifetime(subscription) {
    RunLoop.main.run()
}
```

The above code prints something like this:

```
2022-08-23 17:10:10 +0000: original value: 1
2022-08-23 17:10:11 +0000: original value: 2
2022-08-23 17:10:13 +0000: original value: 3
2022-08-23 17:10:16 +0000: original value: 4
2022-08-23 17:10:20 +0000: original value: 5
2022-08-23 17:10:20 +0000: final value: 5
```